# Need to represent information about a matrix, attached image showing what is needed

Tags: math-mode, formatting, matrices

The following matrix is of size $10 \times 10$, however it is representing an $m \times m$ matrix. Hence I need to signify that the first five columns represent terms $0$ to $\frac{m}{2} - 1$ and the second five columns represent terms $\frac{m}{2}$ to $m$. I have an attached an image of what I need to represent.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{article}   
\RequirePackage[left=37mm,right=30mm,top=35mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{libertine} 
\RequirePackage[small,bf,labelsep=space,
    tableposition=top]{caption} 
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{subfig,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,braket}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\begin{document}

$$
H_{ab}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1           & 1         & 0         & \dots     & \dots     & 0         &  0        & 0         & \dots     & 0 \\
    0           & 0         & 0         & \dots     & \dots     & 1         & -1        & 0         & \dots     & \vdots \\
    \vdots      & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & 0         & 0         & 0         & \dots     & \vdots \\
    \vdots      & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \vdots \\
    0           & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & \dots     & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how I could represent this in LaTeX? If it is not possible to get it to display exactly like in the image I don't mind, I am just looking for a way to represent th e information in the image as clearly as possible. Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a manual placement of the respective braces in a nested `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,array,graphicx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{#1}<{$}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
    \overbrace{\begin{array}{@{}*{5}{C{1.5em}}@{}}
      &&&&
    \end{array}}^{\text{Columns: $0$ to $m/2-1$}}
    \overbrace{\begin{array}{@{}*{5}{C{1.5em}}@{}}
      &&&&
    \end{array}}^{\text{Columns: $m/2$ to $m$}} \hspace*{25pt}\\[-.5\normalbaselineskip]
  H_{ab} = 
  \left.\hspace*{-\nulldelimiterspace}
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}*{10}{C{1.5em}}@{}}
      1           & 1         & 0         & \cdots     & \cdots     & 0         &  0        & 0         & \cdots     & 0 \\
      0           & 0         & 0         & \cdots     & \cdots     & 1         & -1        & 0         & \cdots     & \vdots \\
      \vdots      & \cdots     & \cdots     & \cdots     & \cdots     & 0         & 0         & 0         & \cdots     & \vdots \\
      \vdots      & \cdots     & \cdots     & \cdots     & \cdots     & \cdots     & \cdots     & \cdots     & \cdots     & \vdots \\
      0           & \cdots     & \cdots     & \cdots     & \cdots     & \cdots     & \cdots     & \cdots     & \cdots     & 0 \\ 
    \end{array}\right]\right\} \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\scriptsize Rows: $0$ to $m$}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: ...had been working on this for 10 minutes after I saw the duplicate. :-|

Comment: Appreciate it, very nice!